# How to get back to the terminal output through a bash script after executing scripts on a remote server through an SSH session?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

The scenario is that I need to execute some bash scripts on another Linux server, as well as on the server that I'm gonna execute the script which creates the SSH session. The code is as following.

```
     #!/bin/bash
          #creating ssh session to the remote server

        ssh -t manji@192.168.13.151 'bash -s' << test
        /home/manji/test/falcon_server_start.sh
        /home/manji/test/bos_start.sh
        /home/manji/test/gateway_start.sh
        exit
        test

       #script in the local server
    /home/manula/test/falcon_server_start.sh
```

But I can see the terminal output for the local script execution **only when I hit ctrl+c** after the execution of scripts through the SSH session. **I want to write a bash code to do that automatically without me doing ctrl+c manually.**

Comment: It is likely that one of the scripts is still running on the remote host when you hit _ctrl+c_.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Every script has "successfully executed" message at the end of them. So I hit ctrl+c after seeing that message and not even immediately. And when those scripts are executed locally, they perfectly return to the command line.

Comment: If your script really is indented as you show then the intended here-doc terminating string `test` is never being interpreted as such since it's not at the start of a line. Get rid of the spaces before `test` where it's on it's own line or add the spaces to the start string (`<< '   test'`) or indent with tabs and add a starting `-` (`<<- test`). See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument. If your code is not really indented as you show then fix your question to show us what your code actually looks like.

Comment: Good points from Ed on your immediate problem. In the future, you will run into problems from misusing the key-word `test` (you're ok on this one). For here-docs there are several conventions, `EOD`, `EOF`, `EOS` (End of Data/File/Script) are my favorites. If you're going to write a script or function you want to name as `test` use `mytest` or something else. Good luck

Comment: @EdMorton Edited the code by putting 'test' and removing the space before it. But still the issue is there.

Comment: To be sure, place a `set -x` immediately before the `exit`. Can you see in the trace output that the _exit_ is executed?

Comment: @user1934428 Yes I can see 'exit' in trace mode

Comment: OK, so next put a `set -x` just before `falcon_server_start.sh`. Can you see the trace of this as well?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your current code after you fixed the indenting.

Comment: @EdMorton This is the current code I'm trying. The previous change was just to debug the code to make sure whether the 'exit' is working.

Comment: @user1934428 As I have mentioned before, everything after 'test' will work only if I hit ctrl+c

Comment: I just noticed: In your posting, the word `test` is not written in column 1, but intended (written right below _exit_). Is this a copy&paste error? `test` for sure needs to start in at the start of the input line.

Comment: @manula in response to [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77031735/how-to-get-back-to-the-terminal-output-through-a-bash-script-after-executing-scr?noredirect=1#comment135798265_77031735) about the indenting of `test` you said [Edited the code by putting 'test' and removing the space before it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77031735/how-to-get-back-to-the-terminal-output-through-a-bash-script-after-executing-scr?noredirect=1#comment135803803_77031735) but the code in your question doesn't show any such change - the indenting will still break your here doc.